# JavaEE CDI in Weld: Generic Events?

Tags: events, generics, java-ee-6, cdi, weld

I have an idea for a specific event handling based on generics, but seems like Weld can't handle them. I asked google but couldn't find an alternative CDI extension for this.

**Question**: is there a CDI extension, that can handle event propagation of generic-typed events?

In the following the explicit problem I have.

I have three general events, EntityCreated, EntityChanged and EntityDeleted. The base class for them is defined like this:

```
public abstract class DatabaseEvent<TargetType> {

    public TargetType target;

    public DatabaseEvent(TargetType target) {
        this.target = target;
    }
}
```

The events then are simple inherited classes:

```
public class EntityCreatedEvent<TargetType> extends DatabaseEvent<TargetType> {

    public EntityCreatedEvent(TargetType target) {
        super(target);
    }
}
```

I fire them like this:

```
public abstract class MyHome<EntityType> {

    private EntityType entity;

    @Inject
    Event<EntityCreatedEvent<EntityType>> entityCreatedEvent;

    public void fireCreatedEvent() {
        EntityCreatedEvent<EntityType> payload = new EntityCreatedEvent<EntityType>(entity);
        entityCreatedEvent.fire(payload);
    }
}
```

I want to observe them like this:

```
public void handleProjectCreated(@Observes EntityCreatedEvent<Project> event) { ... }
```

When launching the server Weld tells me it can't handle generic-typed events. The CDI-way of doing things would be to use additional qualifiers instead of the generics to distiguish them, e.g.:

```
public void handleProjectCreated(@Observes @ProjectEvent EntityCreatedEvent event) { ... }
```

However, I fire the events from that `MyHome` base class, where I can't just fire with the `@ProjectEvent`: it might not be a project but another type.

My solution up to now is to skip that typing altogether and handle them like this:

```
public void handleProjectCreated(@Observes EntityCreatedEvent event) { 
    if(event.target instanceof Project) { ... }
}
```

This solution is okay, but not perfect.

Comment: As Fabricio mentions you'd need to use qualifiers. The reason is because of type erasure. At runtime, all of those nicely crafted generic types aren't there for the type system to use during reflection (unless you go through really great lengths and have methods using those types, etc) and type checking during events. You're better off using qualifiers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I guess you can do this with dinamically binding qualifier members. This is what your code would look like:

```
public abstract class MyHome {

    private EntityType entity;

    @Inject
    Event<EntityCreatedEvent> entityCreatedEvent;

    public void fireCreatedEvent() {
        entityCreatedEvent.select(getTypeBinding()).fire(new EntityCreatedEvent(entity));
    }

    private TypeBinding getTypeBinding() {
        return new TypeBinding() {
        public Class<? extends EntityType> value() {return entity.getClass();}
    };
}

@Qualifier
@Target({ PARAMETER, FIELD })
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface EntityTypeQualifier {
    Class<? extends EntityType> value();
}

public abstract class TypeBinding extends AnnotationLiteral<EntityTypeQualifier> implements EntityTypeQualifier {}

//Observers
public void handleEntityType1Created(@Observes @EntityTypeQualifier(EntityType1.class) EntityCreatedEvent event) {}
public void handleEntityType2Created(@Observes @EntityTypeQualifier(EntityType2.class) EntityCreatedEvent event) {}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [this CDI issue points](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-169) it is not possible to fire an without having the type of `T` at runtime.

But, if you have the type of `T` (i.e. you have an instance) you can [use the `Event` as an `Instance`](http://www.next-presso.com/2014/06/you-think-you-know-everything-about-cdi-events-think-again/#qualifiers-don-t-work-with-event-as-they-work-with-beans), and select the event to be fired using a [dynamic type literal](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/CDI-455?focusedCommentId=12996376&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12996376).