# CDI TypeLiteral on generic

Tags: java, cdi

I have a Java application with CDI and I would like to use `javax.enterprise.event.Event<T>` with using a own written `Wrapper<T>` class.

I want to be able to `.fire` the `Wrapper<T>` with the specific values, like `Wrapper<SomeClass>`. The problem is that for every `T` I now have to write
`new javax.enterprise.util.TypeLiteral<Wrapper<SomeClass>>() {}` in order to map it right. Isn't there a way to do this more generic? Because I always can get the class from `SomeClass.getClass()`.

Comment: A piece of code showing the current usage + highlighting the parts you would prefer to make more generic would help. Are we talking about an event in this form? `Event<Wrapper<SomeClass>>`?

Comment: @Siliarus I actually came across a question which is what I wanted to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19135157/javaee-cdi-in-weld-generic-events/19140421